# How to remove script from Google Spreadsheet button

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a Google Spreadsheet I have a simple script, which changes the A1 cell's background colour to red. The script is assigned to a button in the spreadsheets.

After assigning the script I cannot find a way to remove the script or edit the button. I wonder how this is done?

[Here is a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1thhxhrYfBQtMjQEeh5VsurMsO0QLtkMj5geo2g40MGg/edit) to a similar file to see the problem in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Tools > Script Editor inside the spreadsheet and you'll have an option to edit the script.

Answer (score 2):

on a Mac - Cmd-click the image and then the button is highlighted - you can remove it and then add another (edited) one

Answer (score 1):

Right click the button and then open the dropdown menu and remove the script.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the button and then open the drop-down menu and choose assign script. Remove the script name and then click "Cancel" (the only highlighted choice left). I know it sounds crazy because "Cancel" usually means no change but in this case the script will no longer be assigned.